# What are the basic guidelines to use indexing in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

We knows the pros and cons of indexing, but deciding when to index the tables and how to index them is still a question.

Comment: This question has been answered hundreds of times for specific cases on [Database Administrators SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions). I don't think a single question can do this topic justice. It's the kind of thing people write whole books about.

Answer (score 2):

Guidelines to use Index:

1. In order to create effective index, choice of correct columns and types is very important (use indexes only on columns which are used to search the table frequently).
2. It majorly depends on requirement, if the database used for transaction processing should use fewer indexes to allow higher throughput on insert and updates. While in DSS (Decision Support System) and data warehousing where information is static and queries is required largely for the reporting purposes than the modification purposes then heavy indexing is required to optimize the performance.
3. It becomes harder for database engine to work on larger an index key. E.g. an integer key is smaller in size then a character field for holding 100 characters. Keep clustered indexes as short as possible.
   We must try to avoid using character columns in an index, particularly primary key indexes. Integer columns will always have an advantage over character fields in ability to boost the performance of a query.
4. Indexes with a small percentage of duplicated values are always effective.
   An index with a high percentage of unique values is a selective index. Obviously, a unique index is the most selective index of all, because there are no duplicate values. SQL Server will track statistics for indexes and will know how selective each index is. The query optimizer utilizes these statistics when selecting the best index to use for a query.